# Send Whatsapp Message to UnSaved Number

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to send a whatsapp message to a specific number without having to save that contact.

Here is my code

```
 try {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto: " + smsNumber);
    //Timber.e("smsNumber %s", uri.toString());
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and the message I get from that

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPg93.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this Here. This helped me

```
private void openWhatsApp() {
    String smsNumber = "+26377*********";
    boolean isWhatsappInstalled = whatsappInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");
    if (isWhatsappInstalled) {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(smsNumber) + "@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix

        startActivity(sendIntent);
    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(goToMarket);
    }
}

private boolean whatsappInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working for Whatsapp Business edition.

Comment: Remove the + symbol from the phone number, otherwise it gives an exception

Comment: what if multiple whatsapp is installed ?? user needs to choose the intent chooser.

Answer (score 1):

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CODE) {
            if (data != null) {
                val image = data.data
                val number = "9163********"
                    val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                    whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain")
                    whatsappIntent.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "I am sending the image for testing"
                    )
                    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image)
                    whatsappIntent.setType("image/*")
                    whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    whatsappIntent.putExtra(
                        "jid",
                        PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(number) + "@s.whatsapp.net"
                    ) //phone number without "+" prefix
                    startActivity(whatsappIntent)
                }

            
        }
    }

}
```

In Manifest: (below application tag)  (for android 11 support)

```
  <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
    </queries>
```

it will help you and it worked very fine for me

after using this you can select file from storage and send it to unsaved number on whatsapp with some text

Comment: Hi, It is working fine for Android 11, for android 13 any solution or suggestion? Can you plz help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hii u can use this code:

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(smsNumber) + "@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix

    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("**91**"+smsnumber) + "@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Ashi. Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.